# Need a basic template for a dashboard with header, footer and left panel

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Its been a while since I am trying to build a basic template having header, footer, left panel and main section using bootstrap, but I found bootstrap documentation is pretty vague and hard to figure out the actual html template for my requiremnt, especially for newbie like me. Can someone has any basic template using bootstrap like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this boostrap grid generator: http://shoelace.io/. I've added classes to the divs so you know which one is which.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="header col-sm-10"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="nav col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="main col-sm-7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer">
        <div class="footer col-sm-10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My apologies but, I am not quiet sure how we have to use shoelace.io. DO I simply need to copy the above snippet and use it in my project?

Comment: Yes. Shoelace.io is just an online generator for the code you are looking for. The code I've generated for you (above) will provide the framework for your site.

Comment: That was excellent utility to generate a basic html template!. thanks a alot Mech.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As @Mech suggested the link http://shoelace.io/ has an interface where we can customize our basic layout of an `html` page. First design the the header/footer/Main section in this util page (All you need to do is simply select the column and drag it as per the size of the section you are designing for). Dynamically the html content will be generated as you design it.